# New ASP.NET Core Project does not build; "The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.9' was not found."

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

### **Goal**

To make a new ASP.NET Core project target .NET Framework

### **Issue**

When I create a new project I get the error message `The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.9' was not found.` as I try to build the newly created project.

### **Expectation**

Creating a brand new project within Visual Studio should build.

### Repro Steps

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application.
   [image: New Project]
2. Continue through the dialog
   [image: New Project Step 2]
3. Create a .NET Framework ASP.NET Core 2.2 project as Web Application (Model-View-Controller)
   [image: Select .NET Framework/ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web Application (Model-View-Controller)]
4. Run as IIS Express application

   [image: Debug with IIS Express]
5. The build fails, and display this error message.  `rzc discover exited with code -2147450730.`
   [image]
6. If I go to the `Output` tab and look at the build text, I find this:

   ```
   Target ResolveTagHelperRazorGenerateInputs:
   1>  Creating "obj\Debug\net461\MyApp.TagHelpers.input.cache" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
   1>  It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
   1>  The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.9' was not found.
   1>    - The following frameworks were found:
   1>        3.1.3 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   1>        3.1.5 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   1>
   1>  You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
   1>
   1>  The specified framework can be found at:
   1>    - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.9&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86
   1>  C:\Users\joshs\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(79,5): error : rzc discover exited with code -2147450730.
   1>Done building target "ResolveTagHelperRazorGenerateInputs" in project "MyApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
   1>
   1>Done building project "MyApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
   1>
   1>Build FAILED.
   1> 1>C:\Users\joshs\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(79,5): error : rzc discover exited with code -2147450730.
   1>    0 Warning(s)
   1>    1 Error(s)
   1>
   1>Time Elapsed 00:00:23.79
   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
   ```

### Things I have tried

- I have gone to the URL noted in the error message, but get this from Microsoft's download page:

  https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.9&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86

[image: Microsoft download page]

- I tried to create a .NET Framework ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, but that template doesn't exist.  I made a .NET Core ASP.NET Core 3.1 and tried to change the target framework to net471, but that didn't work.
- I thought maybe there was an SDK I'm missing for creating a 3.1 .net Framework project (and there still may be), but I didn't see anything obvious.

  [image]

### My Questions

- How do I create an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project that builds correctly?  I noticed the error message complains about `2.0.9`, why isn't it using `2.2.x`?  To my knowledge 2.0 is EOL, <strike>but 2.2 is LTS (long term support)</strike> *edit: this is wrong*, why can't I download the framework/SDK for this 2.2 project?
- How do I create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project that targets .NET Framework?  (Is this even possible?)

### Misc

- Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.6.2)
- Windows 10 Machine

Comment: Are you ok with building a 3.1 .NET Core project, or does it have to be 2.x?

Comment: Is it possible to have a 3.1 target .NET Framework?  If I target .NET Core, that means I need my clients to install .NET Core runtime OR do a self contained which boosts the install size by dozens of MB.

Comment: To answer my comment question:  ASP.NET Core 3.1 cannot target .NET Framework:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#target-framework-net-framework-support-dropped `Starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, .NET Framework is an unsupported target framework.`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Can you post the solution?

Comment: @ashraydimri Sorry, just seeing your comment now.  I just posted my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve `The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.9' was not found.` issue, this seems to work for me:

1. Close all visual studio instances
2. Go to add/remove programs
3. 'Modify' the 'Microsoft .NET Core 2.0.9 - Windows Server Hosting'
4. Click 'Repair' when the UI dialog opens up
5. Go back into VS and attempt to run the project

I've had this be a problem for me 3 times in the past 4 months, and this always fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading the SDK for 3.1 here :

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

The left side of the page contains SDK's and the right side runtimes. Try and install a 3.1 SDK.

Also, you can download a SDK for 2.2 here that can be used with VS2019:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the **same exact error** and looked to see how Josh Schultz fixed this issue. I didn't have '**Microsoft .NET Core 2.0.9 - Windows Server Hosting**'  but I did have '**Microsoft .Net 5.0.6 - Windows Server Hosting**' I did a repair on that and got past the issue.